# Windows Phone 8: Stuck at creating the Direct3DBackground only when linking a library

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, windows-phone-8, directx-11

I'm porting a Game to Windows Phone 8 and I saw that VS provides two entry points, one with XAML and other native (Windows Phone 8, not 8.1), I successfully get it working with the native example, the game runs fine, but I really need to use the XAML because most of the code we have it's based on it, so I created the project D3D with XAML and without linking my main static library the example runs fine, I can see the cube rotating, but if I link the library the Application get stuck, I only see a black screen.

Debugging step by step on the C# code I found that the last call is:

```
m_d3dBackground = new Direct3DBackground();
```

I press F11 to enter to the method, nothing happens, it get stuck there and I really don't know what it could be, just linking and this fail? why the native solution worked out?

Anyone have some clues?

The only thing I'm using from the static library are some global variables using extern.

EDIT: I removed the Option: Optimize Code on the C# project and now it trhows an exception in the same line of code, it says:

> An exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in PhoneDirect3DXamlAppInterop.DLL but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved the issue:

The game code have a Time class that uses a std::thread, on the constructor calls a method that initializes the thread, the problem was that someone though that would be a good idea to declare a static global variable of the Time class, so the application was stuck on the constructor all the time.

This happened before with other project, it's never a good idea to call functions on the constructor of a global variable using a static library.